# mysql LOAD DATA INFILE fails with Euro sign '€'

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm using php and mysql `LOAD DATA INFILE` from a .csv file.
Some of the cells contain a `'€'` sign and a number and some a `'$'` sign and a number, like: 2.13€, 5.4$
When I load the csv file to the table, the cells with the `'$'` sign are inserted correctly and the cells with the `'€'` are EMPTY.
The related column is defined as the following:

```
VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

How can I make sure that the `'€'` sign will be inserted correctly?

Comment: What is the file's encoding?

Comment: Just now saw the file's encoding is ANSI.

Comment: If you find out what ANSI stands for in your case (it isn't a real encoding) you might be able to use `set names XXXX` and let MySQL do the conversion. But IMHO it's simpler to just save a copy of the as UTF-8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I converted the file encoding:

```
$data = file_get_contents(PATH_TO_CSV_FILE);
$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252');
file_put_contents(PATH_TO_MODIFIED_CSV_FILE, $data);
```

And then loaded it to the table:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '".PATH_TO_MODIFIED_CSV_FILE."' INTO TABLE ...
```

Comment: Self is the master. Could you accept your own answer? So others know this question is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '".PATH_TO_CSV_FILE."' INTO TABLE tbl_name CHARACTER SET latin1
```

latin1 corresponds to Windows-1252 and CP-1252 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following code to detect and convert if necessary:

```
<?php
# Detect and convert to utf-8
$data = file_get_contents($file_full_path);
if(mb_detect_encoding($str,"UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, Windows-1252") != "UTF-8") {
    $data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252');
    file_put_contents($file_full_path, $data);
}
```

But if you know what the character set of the file you are loading you should definetly go with the MySQL command, as it states in [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html):

> The character set indicated by the character_set_database system
>   variable is used to interpret the information in the file. SET NAMES
>   and the setting of character_set_client do not affect interpretation
>   of input. If the contents of the input file use a character set that
>   differs from the default, it is usually preferable to specify the
>   character set of the file by using the CHARACTER SET clause, which is
>   available as of MySQL 5.1.17. A character set of binary specifies “no
>   conversion.”

With the following sintax:

```
LOAD DATA  INFILE 'file_name' INTO TABLE tbl_name [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
```